# Getting sunshine data from latitude and longitude in php

Tags: php, xml

I am working on a site which requires sunshine (hours  of sun in a day )data of a location.
I have the laitude and longitude of the location but now i have to determine the hours of the sun per day on that location.For example say i have a location 'NewYork'.now i need to know 
number of hours of suns in a day in a month .So i have to determine the followimng data
january-8 hours
fabruary-6 hours

means in newyork in january there is 8 hours of sun and so on.
Is some one know from where i can get that data . i am  using php

Comment: Hi, do You have any source where You can get that kind of data (number of hours of sun depending on location)? Using Google Maps API you can get City, Country from lat, long values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who'd've thunk, PHP has a function for that!
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sun-info.php

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Must go search the Python standard library straight away... Nah. Nothing there.

Comment: thank you very much.but are you sure it is calcuating the correct data

Comment: @user As sure as I would be of any standard PHP function to do the right thing (take that as you will). Why not test it with a few known data points?