# Finding the nearest data point and sunshine data in php

Tags: php, file

I am in a big problem.The problem is following

1)I have a .dat file(dat file used to store the data ).It is a 25 MB file which contains 
over 200K rows of latitude and longitudes.Example of one of such row is

-59.083  -26.583    9.4    5.2    3.3    4.3    8.1    6.6    5.3    8.4    8.3   10.0    9.1    5.1

It statrs form the latitude ,longitude,sunshine data (hours) in january,fabruary..and so on to decmber.

I have more than 200K rows  like above.

My task is to calculate the sunshine hours in a particulr latitude and longitude.Suppose i have a latitude =3.86082 and longitude=100.50509 ;.So my task would be to find average sunshine hours per month on this latitude and longitude.but the second problem is that i am not going to have exact match of given latitude and longitude with the ones i have in the file.So first of all i have to find the nearest point and then i have to calculate the sunshine hours.

I am using the following code to calculate the nearest point.But it is taking a huge time beacuse of the bulk of data in the file

```
$file_name='grid_10min_sunp.dat';

$handle = fopen($file_name, "r");

$lat1=13.86082;
$lan1=100.50509;

$lat_lon_sunshines = make_sunshine_dict($file_name);

$closest = 500;
for($c=0;$c<count($lat_lon_sunshines);$c++)
{

$lat2=$lat_lon_sunshines[$c]['lat'];
$lan2=$lat_lon_sunshines[$c]['lan'];
$sunshines=$lat_lon_sunshines[$c]['sunshine'];

$lat_diff = abs(round((float)($lat1), 4)-$lat2);

if ($lat_diff < $closest)
{
    $diff = $lat_diff +  abs(round((float)($lan1), 4)-$lan2); 

     if($diff < $closest)
     {
              $closest = $diff;
            $sunshinesfinal=$sunshines;
     }      
}
$sunshines='';

}
print_r($sunshinesfinal);die;
```

the function make_sunshine_dict($file_name ) also goes throgh each line of the file and prepares an array as following

```
$sunshines_dict = array();      

  $f = file_get_contents($file_name);

  $handle = fopen($file_name, "r");

  while($buffer = fgets($handle))
  {

   $tok = strtok($buffer, " \n\t");

   $lat=$tok;

   $latArray[]=$tok;

   $tok = strtok(" \n\t");

   $months = '';

   $months = array();

   for ($k = 0; $tok !== false; $k+=1) 
   {

   if($k==0)
   {
   $lan=$tok;
   $lanArray[]=$tok;
   }

   if($k!=0)
   {
        $months[] = $tok ;
         "month $k : ".$months[$k]."<br>";

   }

    $tok = strtok(" \n\t");
    }

    $data[$kkk]['lat']=$lat;
    $data[$kkk]['lan']=$lan;

    foreach($months as $m=>$sunshine)
    {


         $sunshines=array();
          $sumD = 0;

          $iteration= 31;

          for($n=1;$n<=$iteration;$n++)
          {
              $J = ($m+1)*$n; 



             $P = asin(.39795*cos(.2163108 + 2*atan(.9671396*tan(.00860*($J-186)))));



          $value=(sin(0.8333*pi/180) + sin($lat*pi/180)*sin($P))/(cos($lat*pi/180)*cos($P));

            /* $value ? ($value > 1 and 1) : $value;

             $value ? ($value < -1 and -1): $value;*/


          $D = 24 - ((24/pi) * acos($value));



           $sumD = $sumD + $D;

             }

                $sunshinesdata=(($sumD/30)*(float)($sunshine)*.01);

           $data[$kkk]['sunshine'][$m]=$sunshinesdata; 

          $sunshines='';
    }

    }
return $data;
```

Please help and please let me know if you require more information

And please remenber i can not use default php function for sunshine information here beacsue i am also taking cloud cover and other factors into consideration

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is? And what do you mean by taking cloud cover into consideration?

Comment: @user977003: Please don't post duplicate questions. Related: [Running operation on a text file of 25 mb data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634536/running-operation-on-a-text-file-of-25-mb-data); [Getting sunshine data from latitude and longitude in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608557/getting-sunshine-data-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-php)

Comment: sorry hakre sir.but i have sreach the whole internet and also those question are posted by my  juniors .they could not make it right so i asked the question in a preciszed manner

Comment: are the data points sorted in any particular order? if they were sorted by lat/long you could use fseek and do a binary search to find the closest point. that might help make the script faster. The only other way to speed it up (and what would probably be best) is to use a database.

Comment: means look at the formula i used to filter the record by following line of code  $J = ($m+1)*$n; 



             $P = asin(.39795*cos(.2163108 + 2*atan(.9671396*tan(.00860*($J-186)))));



          $value=(sin(0.8333*pi/180) + sin($lat*pi/180)*sin($P))/(cos($lat*pi/180)*cos($P));

            /* $value ? ($value > 1 and 1) : $value;

             $value ? ($value < -1 and -1): $value;*/


          $D = 24 - ((24/pi) * acos($value));



           $sumD = $sumD + $D;

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the code looks wrong (in terms of just figuring out the sunshine hours).  Although, I'll admit, I'm lost as to what you are doing in the `make_sunshine_dict` function.

In terms of helping you speed things up, you are reading your file twice:

```
 $f = file_get_contents($file_name);
 $handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
```

Also, you can map Lat/Long coordinates into a grid.  In other words, make a 2 dimensional array where each row and each column represents 1 degree of latitude and 1 degree of longitude, respectively.  As you read in your file, dump entries into the correct lat/long bucket in the grid.  When you need to find the location closest to a given lat/lon then you only need to compare that location against the points in its bucket.

Answer (score -1):

Load the .dat into a SQL database every x interval in a Cron job and then just query the database like you always would.